# In Redux dispatch need to call reset formik details after login success, how to send that using callback function?

Tags: redux, formik

In Redux dispatch need to call reset formik details after login success, how to send that using callback function?

```
function handleLogin(values, { setErrors, setSubmitting, resetForm }) {
    const CREDENTIALS = {
        url: `/login `,
        method: 'post',
        data: values,
        setErrors,
    };
    /**
     * dispatch will call redux function with CREDENTIALS
     */
    dispatch(login(CREDENTIALS));
    /**
     * after login success need to call this fucntion, to reset form
     */
    function handleLoginSuccess() {
        resetForm({});
        setSubmitting(false);
    }
}

In dispatch now I am calling redux method, after login success need to reset the formik form, but that can't be outside of this handleLogin, how to handle this?
```

Comment: Can you show the `login(...)` action implementation?

Comment: @TomaszRozmus Thats is just axios api call

Comment: If that "axios api call" returns a promise, try `dispatch(login(CREDENTIALS)).then(() => {
  resetForm({});
  setSubmitting(false);
}) ` 
I am really curious how that `login(...)` action looks like, please paste it's code.

Comment: I see that you pass `setErrors` to CREDENTIALS, you can also pass `setSubmitting` or `resetForm` and handle it inside `login` action. The solution really depends on your redux implementation (side-effects handling, other middlewares). Generally, I was using `meta` props for such purposes. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction#using-prepare-callbacks-to-customize-action-contents

Comment: ```
Redux action creator
    const login = (credentials) =>     
      dispatch =>                  
        axios.get(credentials)  
        .then(res => res.data)
        .then(user => {
          dispatch(LoginCompleted(user))
// here I need to call handleLoginSuccess() here
        })